# How to add discount per item in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

While integrating Salesforce into Netsuite, when creating a Sales Order, I want to be able to add discount per item (and not a single discount for the entire SO)

Going through the [help at Netsuite](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/partners/integration/download/NetSuiteWebServicesRecordsGuide_2_0_0.pdf) I can't figure if this is possible or not.

It mentions of "Discount Items" - What I understand of this, is that there are "Special Items" that give discount. This is far from the behavior I want. (plus it will duplicate the invoice size)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Discounts in netsuite are "basically" items so you have a couple of choices here:
A) add a discount item for every item on line
B) add a discount field on every item and apply conditionally on the sales order
C)  you could manage B on a different record and match item vs discount plan = discount %

The problem with B is that you wouldn't keep record of when the discount was applied,  which is not the case for A and can be avoided in C by populating tue discount record there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into "Price Levels" yet?  This will allow you to specify a discount amount on the line itself.  Price levels can be set as percentages of the "Base price."

Comment: Did this work for you?  If so, will you mark my response as the answer?